# Strategy to find function satsfying that $f''(x)$ is not diff at some points.

Tags: calculus, functions

Does there exist a function $f$ that is derivable at all points on its domain (derivable means first derivate is there which is continuous ) but $f''(x)$ (double derivative) does not exist at some points? Strategy: What I thought of was to think of a function which is not differentiable and then integrate it to get the desired function but I think there maybe another way of doing this without going reverse. This question I asked because I was thinking to prove by contradiction by this statement in a problem I was solving out.

Comment: I don't understand the question, If $f$ is derivable at all points on its domain, then there exists $f'$ at all points on domain of $f$

Comment: f" Sir i am saying

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414729/only-once-differentiable there are even functions that are differentiable everywhere once but nowhere twice.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Uznanski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that integrating a continuous function will give you a differentiable one: Take $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ integrable, but not differentiable (for example, $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$), then $$g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$$is differentiable with derivative $f$, but $g'$ is not differentiable at $0$ (where $f$ has a cuspid).