# Give an example of a function f(x)

Tags: calculus

For which *f* '(0) exists, but *f* ''(0) does not exist, and explain why:

Trick question that I cant seem to solve.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I haven't the time to look for it now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78825/example-of-a-function-that-is-not-twice-differentiable?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Which function you know is continuous but not differentiable at 0?
It's anti-derivative will be differentiable once but not twice at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at 0. Integrate it, $F(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}$ if $x<0$ and $F(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ if $x >= 0$.

It is an example, there are a lot of other example, some more interessting i suppose, maybe with sinus and a fraction.